# MS Access Populating Data in Column with Data from another table (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm needing help with a (probably very basic) command. On a test spreadsheet I have been asked to populate a column with data from another table in MS Access. However, to add the data from table 1 to table 2 it relies on another set of data to be matched with it.

In table 1 there is 2 Tables "Customer Number" and "CustomerID" - Both of which are full data sets 40,000 entries so I can't copy paste.

In table 2 the "CustomerID" is there but there are no entries.There are all entries for "Customer Number".

I need to add the customerid from table 1 to table 2 but only when the customer number is matching on both tables.

I have tried using Join function and insert but I only have been using access for about 3 days and need some help. Sorry for the longwinded explanation and hope the question is legible.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [provide](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample (!) data and expected result. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Answer (score 1):

Does this work with `JOIN`?

```
UPDATE table2 t2 JOIN
       table1 t1
       ON t2.CustomerNumber = t1.CustomerNumber
    SET t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID;
```

Comment: This works on Access 2007 if you replace "JOIN" with "INNER JOIN".